# Relativistic Derivatives

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electric-fields

My problem ist about accelerated motion in SRT.
For example consider a charqed particle with mass m and charge q in an homogeneous Electric Field pointing in x-Direction.

We know that
$  \frac{dp^1}{d\tau} =  \gamma E q$ and $m\frac{dx^0}{d\tau^2} = \frac{dp^0}{d\tau} =  \gamma E q v$.
Now i've seen that you can use $\gamma =  \frac{dt}{d\tau}$ to derive the "relativistic Lorentz Force".
My question is:
How do we know that $\frac{dt}{d\tau} = \gamma$ if we have an accelerated motion and thus $t(\tau)$ is not just linear. Is it just a pre-condition we have that $\frac{dt}{d\tau} = \gamma(v)$ and if yes how do we know that our solution for $t(\tau)$ satisfies this condition?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation $dt/d\tau = \gamma$ is automatically true for any massive particle's worldline because of the definition of $\tau$.  Here's why:

If we consider an infinitesimal spacetime displacement $dx^\mu = (dt, d\vec{x})$ along a worldline, then the infinitesimal proper time between these two events satisfies
$$
d\tau^2 = dt^2 - |d\vec{x}^2|
$$
which implies that
$$
\left(\frac{d\tau}{dt}\right)^2 = 1 - \left( \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} \right)^2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{d\tau}{dt} = \sqrt{1 - v^2} = \frac{1}{\gamma}. 
$$
So the particle's "internal clock" will always tick along at such a rate such that $dt/d\tau = \gamma$, even if it accelerates.